# What is the hypothesis in .get_influence().cooks_distance in python?

Tags: python, outliers

Suppose i ended up with a cook's distance array like this:
[image]

and looking at the first element (cook's distance = 0.368 and p-value = 0.701).

How can i interpret the p-value? It is larger than 0.05 and reject the H0, but what is H0?

example obtained from https://www.statology.org/cooks-distance-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p value is not the p value you get from a hypothesis test. If you check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance), Cook's distance follows a F distribution with p and n-p degrees of freedom. So the p-value you get is actually the probability of observing a value more extreme than that, with the assumptions of a linear model that is.

We can look at the [source code](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/stats/outliers_influence.html#OLSInfluence) for `statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence.OLSInfluence` which is the function called for calculating cooks distance:

```
def cooks_distance(self):
        """Cook's distance and p-values

        Based on one step approximation d_params and on results.cov_params
        Cook's distance divides by the number of explanatory variables.

        p-values are based on the F-distribution which are only approximate
        outside of linear Gaussian models.

        Warning: The definition of p-values might change if we switch to using
        chi-square distribution instead of F-distribution, or if we make it
        dependent on the fit keyword use_t.
        """
        cooks_d2 = (self.d_params * np.linalg.solve(self.cov_params,
                                                    self.d_params.T).T).sum(1)
        cooks_d2 /= self.k_vars
        from scipy import stats
        # alpha = 0.1
        # print stats.f.isf(1-alpha, n_params, res.df_modelwc)
        # TODO use chi2   # use_f option
        pvals = stats.f.sf(cooks_d2, self.k_vars, self.results.df_resid)

        return cooks_d2, pvals
```

The relevant line is `pvals = stats.f.sf(cooks_d2, self.k_vars, self.results.df_resid)` . So you calculate cooks distance and look at its 1-cdf value on the F distribution.

It is similar to how you obtain the p-value for a one sided t-test, you ask what is the probability of observing a t-statistic more extreme than that obtained from the test.

Comment: so in my example, cook's distance = 0.368 and p-value = 0.701, i should interpret it as "there's 70.1% chance that i will get a value larger than 0.368"?

Comment: yes it's more or less like that, if the residues of your model follows a normal distribution.as also noted in the code above ```based on the F-distribution which are only approximate outside of linear Gaussian models.```